# SyntaxError: invalid syntax when printing class name

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

In a Jupyter notebook I have this variable `train_dataset`.

I would like to see what is its class using this:

```
print train_dataset.__class__.__name__
```

However, I'm getting this error:

```
print train_dataset.__class__.__name__
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This `print type(train_dataset)` has the same result.

Comment: You are using Python 2 syntax with Python 3; `print()` is now a function.

Comment: `print(train_dataset.__class__.__name__)` ?